# I can't save a 3 word string in binary files C++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I was trying to make a program to save bibliographic references, but when the title has more than 2 words, the program crashes. The programs asks about some info about the book: Name, author, editorial, publication date, amount of pages and an ID to search it.
Here is an example:

```
Id: 0
Name: Howls Moving Castle
Author: Hayao Miyazaki
Editorail: Studio Ghibli
Publication date: 2001
Amount of pages: 256
```

(I know that Howl's Moving Castle its a movie, just an example)

The binary file is saved, but when I open the program and search for the reference, the program crashes with this exit code: 3221225477

Here's the code:

```
#ifndef LIBRO_H
#define LIBRO_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Libro {
private:
    int id;
    string nombreLibro;
    string autor;
    string nombreEditorial;
    int annoPublicacion;
    int cantidadPaginas;
public:
    Libro();
    int getId();
    string getNombreLibro();
    string getAutor();
    string getNombreEditorial();
    int getAnnoPublicacion();
    int getCantidadPaginas();
    
    void setId(int id);
    void setNombreLibro(string nombreLibro);
    void setAutor(string autor);
    void setNombreEditorial(string nombreEditorial);
    void setAnnoPublicacion(int annoPublicacion);
    void setCantidadPaginas(int cantidadPaginas);
    
    void getData();
    void putData();
    
    string toString();
    ~Libro();
};

#endif
```

```
#include "Libro.h"

Libro::Libro() {
    this->id=0;
    this->nombreLibro="";
    this->autor="";
    this->nombreEditorial="";
    this->annoPublicacion=0;
    this->cantidadPaginas=0;
}

int Libro::getId()
{
    return this->id;
}

string Libro::getNombreLibro()
{
    return this->nombreLibro;
}

string Libro::getAutor()
{
    return this->autor;
}

string Libro::getNombreEditorial()
{
    return this->nombreEditorial;
}

int Libro::getAnnoPublicacion()
{
    return this->annoPublicacion;
}

int Libro::getCantidadPaginas()
{
    return this->cantidadPaginas;
}

void Libro::setId(int id)
{
    this->id=id;
}

void Libro::setNombreLibro(string nombreLibro)
{
    this->nombreLibro=nombreLibro;
}

void Libro::setAutor(string autor)
{
    this->autor=autor;
}

void Libro::setNombreEditorial(string nombreEditorial)
{
    this->nombreEditorial=nombreEditorial;
}

void Libro::setAnnoPublicacion(int annoPublicacion)
{
    this->annoPublicacion=annoPublicacion;
}

void Libro::setCantidadPaginas(int cantidadPaginas)
{
    this->cantidadPaginas=cantidadPaginas;
}

void Libro::getData()
{
    int pId;
    string pNombreLibro;
    string pAutor;
    string pNombreEditorial;
    int pAnnoPublicacion;
    int pCantidadPaginas;
    
    cout<<"\tId: ";
    cin>>pId;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\tNombre del libro: ";
    getline(cin, pNombreLibro);
    cout<<"\tNombre del Autor: ";
    getline(cin, pAutor);
    cout<<"\tNombre de la editorial: ";
    getline(cin, pNombreEditorial);
    cout<<"\tAnno de publicacion: ";
    cin>>pAnnoPublicacion;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"\tCantidad de paginas: ";
    cin>>pCantidadPaginas;
    cin.ignore();
    
    this->setId(pId);
    this->setNombreLibro(pNombreLibro);
    this->setAutor(pAutor);
    this->setNombreEditorial(pNombreEditorial);
    this->setAnnoPublicacion(pAnnoPublicacion);
    this->setCantidadPaginas(pCantidadPaginas);
}

void Libro::putData()
{
    cout<<"\tId: "<<this->getId()<<endl;
    cout<<"\tNombre del Libro: "<<this->getNombreLibro()<<endl;
    cout<<"\tNombre del autor: "<<this->getAutor()<<endl;
    cout<<"\tNombre de la editorial: "<<this->getNombreEditorial()<<endl;
    cout<<"\tAnno de publicacion: "<<this->getAnnoPublicacion()<<endl;
    cout<<"\tCantidad de paginas: "<<this->getCantidadPaginas()<<endl;
}



Libro::~Libro() {
    
}
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include "Libro.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    Libro lib1;
    fstream stream;
    
    stream.open("archivo.txt", ios::binary | ios::out);
    char respuesta='y';
    
    while(respuesta=='y' || respuesta=='Y')
    {
        cout << "\tIncluir informacion Libro: " << endl;
        lib1.getData();
        stream.write((char *)&lib1, sizeof(lib1));
        cout<<"\tArchivo Agregado!\n";
        cout<<"\n\tDesea insertar mas informacion ? (y/n)..";
        cin>>respuesta;
    }
    stream.close();
    int numEs;
    long pos;
    char encontrado='f';
    
    
    stream.open("archivo.txt", ios::in);
    
    cout<<"\n Cual es el numero del libro a buscar: ";
    cin>>numEs;
    
    stream.seekg(0);
    while(!stream.eof())
    {
        pos=stream.tellg();
        stream.read((char *)&lib1, sizeof(lib1));
        if(lib1.getId() == numEs)
        {
            lib1.putData();
            stream.seekg(pos);
            encontrado='t';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(encontrado=='f')
    {
        cout<<"\nNo se encuentra el libro..!!\n";
        cout<<"Presione una tecla para continuar...\n";
        exit(2);
    }
    stream.close();
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't write an object that is not trivially copyable to file in this way.  It just doesn't work (because the object is not laid out sequentially in memory).

Comment: Also, next time, [mre] please (with emphasis on the word _minimal_).

Comment: *The binary file is saved* -- Make one of those strings have 100 or so characters.  You will see that the file does not contain any information concerning that string, only junk.  Second, `sizeof(lib1)` is a compile-time value -- it has no idea how many characters those `std::string` members contain, thus this line: `stream.write((char *)&lib1, sizeof(lib1));` will never work.  Read up on *object serialization*.  Last, what book or website gave you the information that you can write non-POD C++ classes in this manner?  It is totally wrong.

Comment: You cannot `fwrite` or `fread` non-POD C++ objects. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie A friend did, I think that it's better that I read about object serialization, as you said)